# Is it possible to add a jar file to the ant class path from build.xml?

Tags: ant, pmd

I want to add the PMD jar to the ant build but I want to check in the jar to source control so other developers do not have to modify their environment. Hence copying to the ant lib folder is not the ideal situation. Is there another way to add that jar file to ant classpath?

Comment: How about checking in utility libraries to `util/lib`? And refer to them in your `build.xml`. That way everyone who takes a checkout will get the correct JAR files.

Comment: Wouldn't that just add them to the class path of the javac but not the actual ant class path?

Comment: If you mean Ant should be able to use the PMD task then I believe the <taskdef/> task is the way to go. If that is not what you mean then I haven't understood your question correctly.

Comment: Even taskdef needs the jar to be in the class path See Mark's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of managing storing jars in the source code revision system. I understand why, but SCM systems are unsuited to storing large binary objects.

Here's a few alternative options for making your build repeatable across machines:

## Option 1: Create a "bootstrap" target

Use the ANT [get task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) to download the PMD jar into a directory accessible by ANT, namely $HOME/.ant/lib:

```
<target name="bootstrap" description="Install jars required by build">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=pmd/pmd/4.3/pmd-4.3.jar" dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/pmd.jar"/>
</target>
```

## Option 2: Use dependency management

[Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) can be used to manage all your build's dependencies (Similar to Maven)

The advantage of using ivy is that it can be used to manage all your build classpaths (using configurations):

```
<target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="build"/>
</target>
```

A file called **ivy.xml** will then list your project's dependencies

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="com.myspotontheweb" module="demo"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="compile" description="Required to compile application"/>
        <conf name="build"   description="Required by the ANT build"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- compile dependencies -->
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.6.4" conf="compile->default"/>

        <!-- build dependencies -->
        <dependency org="pmd" name="pmd" rev="4.3" conf="build->default"/>    
    </dependencies>

</ivy-module>
```

This option appears more complex, but it can be used to manage all 3rd party jars. It also have the benefit of understand the transitive dependencies a jar might have on other jars.

## Option 3: Sonar

I don't know if you've heard of the [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) project?

A single jar file can be installed using options 1 or 2 and this will automatically download the jars required for the following analysis tools:

- PMD
- Findbugs
- Checkstyle

Well worth investigating!

Comment: Thx I will probably use Option 1. BTW I completely agree about not storing jars in SCM but this is a project I have inherited from another team and need a stop gap measure until I can convince people to discard ant and go to maven.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail Understood. Unless you have an adventurous development team, you'll discover that Maven will be a hard sell.... That is why I favour using ivy as a stop gap. Another build tool to consider is Gradle. It has better support for ANT and can support a baby-steps approach to weaning developers off ANT :-)